# Game of life in C#

Tags: algorithm, conways-game-of-life

Can we represent Conway's game of life using graphs?

And is there any example out there? Or any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing A "Conway's Game of Life" Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823/writing-a-conways-game-of-life-program)

Comment: I want an implementation using Graphs

Comment: @Henk: I want an implementation using graphs.

Comment: And, if you need a graph library for .NET you can use quickgraph --> http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/

Comment: An arbitrary graph seems like a bad data structure for standard Life played on a rectangular grid. Graphs are unnecessarily large and slow, it's not easy or fast to convert them to bitmaps, and they typically do not exploit any of the regularity in the rectangularity of the lattice. Nor do you get interesting space/time compressions like you can do with Gosper's algorithm. **Can you explain why you want to use a graph?** Do you want to experiment with Life on an unusual topology other than a rectangular grid, for instance?

Comment: @saurabh: The abundance of details in the question confused me, I thought it was a misspelled grahics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://igoro.com/archive/self-printing-game-of-life-in-c/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=6819

http://forums.asp.net/t/1063384.aspx

Comment: Is there a way we can do it using graphs?

Comment: @saurabh I don't see how graphs can be applied here.

Answer (score 2):

They used to calculate it by hand, so yes - yes you can!

I suspect that's not the answer you want to hear though, can you clarify your question ?